# Sorting PHP array(s) based on their initial keys?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort my initial array(s) that contain many keys and values inside, into array(s) sorted by a specific key, and all the values for that key in a single array based on the key.

So here's the array I have:

```
$Before = Array(Array("id" => 1, "name" => "Dogs"), 
                Array("id" => 2, "name" => "Lions"), 
                Array("id" => 3, "name" => "Tigers"));
```

And this is the array that I would like to end up with:

```
$After = Array("ids"   => Array(1, 2, 3), 
               "names" => Array("Dogs", "Lions", "Tigers"));
```

I hope that makes sense. I found it easier to show you an example, as oppose to describing it.

Comment: This looks more like a restructure than a sort

Comment: Yeah, wasn't exactly sure how to phrase it.

Comment: If you did need it sorted as well as restructured, could try using the code in example #3 of http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$after = array(
    'ids'   => array(),
    'names' => array()
);

foreach($before as $row){
    $after['ids'][]   = $row['id'];
    $after['names'][] = $row['name'];
}

var_dump($after);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_reduce`

```
$After = array_reduce($Before, function ($a, $b) {
    $a['ids'][] = $b['id'];
    $a['names'][] = $b['name'];
    return $a;
});
```

[Live DEMO](http://eval.in/32585)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
foreach ($input as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $field => $value) {
        $result[$field][] = $value;
    }
}
    var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$After = array();
foreach ($Before as $a) {
    $After['ids'][] = $a['id'];
    $After['names'][] = $a['name'];
}
```

This should work :)